# pre-commit isort no module named 'setuptools'

Tags: python, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, isort

I am trying to run pre-commit hooks, but they fail when they come across the isort hook which throws the error below:

```
  File "/home/el/.cache/pre-commit/repoffrjhcx0/py_env-python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py", line 92, in create_module
    return importlib.import_module('setuptools._distutils')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

I am using docker, and I have checked that setuptools is installed on both my machine globally, and on my docker. I do not understand why this error occurs. I think isort sets up it's own environment, but then why would it be not installed since it is defined in their config file [pyproject.toml](https://github.com/PyCQA/isort/blob/c6a41965247a858a0afd848fbebfca18b8983917/pyproject.toml#L48).

Below are my pre-commit and isort configs:

.pre-commit-config.yaml

```
repos:
- repo: https://github.com/pycqa/isort
  rev: 5.8.0
  hooks:
    - id: isort
      args: ["--multi-line=5", "--line-length=120", "--use-parentheses", "--filter-files"]
      exclude: "migrations"
      stages: [commit]
```

tox.ini

```
[isort]
line_length=120
skip_glob=*migrations*
multi_line_output=5
sections=FUTURE,STDLIB,THIRDPARTY,FIRSTPARTY,LOCALFOLDER
use_parentheses=true
include_trailing_comma=true
lines_between_types=1
lines_after_imports=2
[testenv:isort]
deps =
    isort
commands =
    isort . --check-only --diff
```

Python version on system: 3.10.1

Python version on docker: 3.8

I appreciate any help!

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/ Is this can help you?

Comment: @VincentBénet thank you for your response. setuptools is installed on both system wide and docker, but precommit isort fails to see that for some reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this was [a bug in setuptools](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2980) which has already been fixed (see also [the pinned issue on `isort`](https://github.com/PyCQA/isort/issues/1874))

you can work around this bug by setting the following environment variable:  `SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib`

the version of `setuptools` comes from the version of `virtualenv` you're using, so you may want to upgrade to get the correct version

here's a longer [summary of what went wrong with setuptools](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/2178):

> here's the relevant things to follow up on:
>
> - https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2353
> - https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6264
> - https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2980
>
> why we're suddenly seeing this:
>
> - the latest virtualenv release upgraded setuptools to 60.1.0 (despite what the [changelog
>   says](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/36a4a18bee79971741735ac7cb28275274616c6d/docs/changelog.rst#v20110-2021-12-28)
>   it was [upgraded to 60.1.0
>   here](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/pull/2252))
> - setuptools 60.* changes the default to using the setuptools-embedded `distutils` rather than the stdlib distutils
> - setuptools does this by way of a `.pth` file which redirects imports of `distutils` to `setuptools._distutils`
> - during pip's isolated builds (triggered by `pyproject.toml`, for example to install `isort` via `poetry`) pip attempts to clear the
>   current `sys.path` of the enclosing environment and isolates to the
>   pyproject.toml-installed build dependencies, but it's a bit too late
>   as the `.pth` files from the enclosing environment are applied.  so in
>   this environment `setuptools` is not installed, but its import hooks
>   are

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit

Comment: This is such a detailed answer. I really appreciate your help! Also great job with pre-commit! Thank you